# Char list to String using foldBack

Tags: list, f#, type-inference

For an assignment, I am looking for a way to concatenate a string from a list of chars using List.foldBack.

What I've come up with so far:

```
let (.+) (x1:string) (x2:char) = x1 + System.Char.ToString(x2)
let implode xs:char list = List.foldBack(fun acc elem -> (.+) acc elem) xs ""
```

This does however give me the following error message:

```
This expression was expected to have type
    char list    
but here has type
    string
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the desired result using foldBack

Comment: Change `implode` to this `let implode (xs : char) (l : char list) = List.foldBack(fun acc elem -> (.+) acc elem) xs ""` and you will get a new error but it should help you figure out your problem. Since you said assignment I take it that it is homework and you can learn more by getting a nudge than an answer.

Comment: Version with List.fold : https://dotnetfiddle.net/lPRKsd

Comment: try to change to the List.foldBack

Comment: Your question has been resolved?

Comment: @GuyCoder helped me out. Ended up using an implementation close to the one suggested by kvb

Comment: @FoggyFinder resolved indeed. Actually ended up using your referred List.fold version for a similar assignment. Thanks

Comment: No surprised. kvb is one of the top F# people in the world if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your annotation `:char list` applies to `implode`'s return type, not to `xs`.  You need to parenthesize it if you want the latter (`(xs:char list)`).
2. `List.foldBack` needs to take a function with signature `'a -> 'b -> 'b` for some `'a` and `'b`, but `(.+)` has type `string -> char -> string`, which doesn't quite match.

Comment: Winded up using the following. Assignment hinted foldBack, but fold seemd more intuitive?

`let (.+) (x1:string) (x2:char) = x1 + (string x2)

let implode ((xs:char list)) = List.fold(fun elem acc -> (.+) elem acc) "" xs`

Answer (score 1):

Besides of writing `(xs : char list)`, you also need to order the arguments for `(.+)` correctly.

```
List.foldBack : ('a   -> 'b     -> 'b)     -> 'a   list -> 'b     -> 'b
Required        (char -> string -> string) -> char list -> string -> string
Actual  ... (fun acc     elem   -> (.+) acc elem)  ...
which is      : (string -> char -> string)
```

If you swap `acc` and `elem`, which becomes `(.+) elem acc`, your code will compile.

```
List.foldBack : ('a   -> 'b     -> 'b)     -> 'a   list -> 'b     -> 'b
Required        (char -> string -> string) -> char list -> string -> string
Actual  ... (fun acc     elem   -> (.+) elem acc)
```

where `(.+) : string -> char -> string`

Or as Foggy Finder suggested, change the operator `(.+)` so that their arguments are swapped (`let (.+) (x1:char) (x2:string) = System.Char.ToString(x1) + x2`), then we can use `List.foldBack (.+) xs ""`.

Comment: I think it's easier to change the operator: (.+) : char -> string -> string  ... => List.foldBack((.+)) xs ""